# Prolog returning H = 0+1+1 rather than H = 2

Tags: prolog

I've been learning recursion in prolog and it seems to work but the output is in a very strange format;

```
mins_to_hours(In, H, M):-
    In < 60,
    H is 0,
    M is In.
mins_to_hours(In, H, M):-
    In > 59,
    H = H1 + 1,
    In1 = In - 60,
    mins_to_hours(In1, H1, M).
```

Is my code and given the query `mins_to_hours(135, H, M).`
The response is

```
H = 0+1+1,
M = 15
```

I'm just confused why the minute works but the hours doesn't.
The program is supposed to convert minutes into hours and minutes.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When reasoning over integers, use for example the predicate `(#=)/2` to express **equality** of arithmetic expressions.

For example, using GNU Prolog:

```
mins_to_hours(In, H, M):-
    In #< 60,
    H #= 0,
    M #= In.
mins_to_hours(In, H, M):-
    In #> 59,
    H #= H1 + 1,
    In1 #= In - 60,
    mins_to_hours(In1, H1, M).
```

Thus, I am simply using `(#=)/2` to express *equality*, `(#<)/2` to express "less than", and `(#>)/2` to express "greater than".

Example query and answer:

```
| ?- mins_to_hours(135, H, M).

H = 2
M = 15 ? ;

no
```

It also works in other directions, for example:

```
| ?- mins_to_hours(Mins, 2, 15).

Mins = 135 ? ;

no
```

The **most general query** works too:

```
| ?- mins_to_hours(Mins, H, M).

H = 0
M = _#2(0..59)
Mins = _#2(0..59) ? ;

H = 1
M = _#72(0..59)
Mins = _#2(60..119) ? ;

H = 2
M = _#136(0..59)
Mins = _#2(120..179) ?
```

In other Prolog systems, you may have to import a library to use such relations over integers. For example, in SICStus Prolog, YAP and SWI, use `library(clpfd)`.

In contrast, the predicate `(=)/2` you are currently using denotes **syntactic unification**, and does not *evaluate* arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

@mat has the correct answer regarding reasoning over integers.

The reason why you see `H = 0+1+1` is because in Prolog `+` is just another functor. That is, `H1 + 1` is equivalent to `'+'(H1, 1)`, and the `=/2` operator is *not* an assignment as it is in other languages. It does *unification* of terms. So to say, `H = H1 + 1` simply *unifies* `H` with the term `'+'(H1, 1)` or `H1 + 1`. If `H1` is unified with `0`, then `H` will be unified with the term `0 + 1`. If later on `H1` is unified with `0 + 1` and you execute `H = H1 + 1`, then `H` will have the value `0 + 1 + 1`, and so on.

If you want to execute an arithmetic expression, you can use `is/2`. This is described in the Prolog documentation:

```
H is H1 + 1
```

This will actually evaluate `H1 + 1` assuming it is a valid arithmetic expression (which it is in this case) and all the variables are instantiated with numeric values. There are other operators in Prolog which will perform arithmetic expression evaluation: `</2`, `>/2`, `=:=/2`, etc, as well as the CLP(FD) operators, `#=/2`, etc, as described in @mat's answer. These are aall described in the Prolog documentation.

Conversely, you are using `is/2` where you should be using unification. This:

```
mins_to_hours(In, H, M):-
    In < 60,
    H is 0,           % 0 is a trivial expression and doesn't need evaluating
    M is In.          % In is a trivial expression and doesn't need evaluating
```

Should be written as:

```
mins_to_hours(In, H, M):-
    In < 60,
    H = 0,
    M = In.
```

Or more concisely as:

```
min_to_hours(In, 0, In) :- In < 60.
```